# Does name mangling apply to virtual functions in c++?

Tags: c++, virtual

We all know that all the functions in C++ are name mangled during the compile time only, so is this applied to virtual functions too?

Comment: It depends on the compiler. In general, however, most compilers mangle virtual functions as well.

Comment: Name-mangling is not an inherent property of C++, it is just a technique that implementations commonly use to cope with limitations of outdated linkers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Member function names are mangled.  They need to embed their argument types so that you can overload them with different argument types.

In theory, a compiler could encode the argument types in some other way, but at some level each function body needs to be labelled by (and to have references to it resolved using) both the function name and its argument types.  All major compilers certainly use mangling.

Comment: so according to rob,i understand that all the function names are mangled at runtime but by making the function as virtual then the function address to resolve is done at runtime..correct me if i'm worng.

Comment: Names are mangled at compile time.  The mangled names are embedded in the executable's (or shared library's) symbol table if necessary to resolve references between DLLs/shared objects.

Answer (score 1):

Name mangling is unrelated to member functions being virtual or not; after all virtual methods can be called non-virtually just like any member function. Only if the compiler could be certain that a virtual method is exclusively called through the vtable, it might avoid generating any linker symbol at all for the method (just inserting its address in the vtable instead). But I don't think there is any practical way a compiler can know that a method is not being called directly in another compilation unit (as it can for functions that are visible only in the current compilation unit).